# Kill all processes that are using qt5

Tags: linux, shell, process, kill, qt

I would like to run a python script with conflicts with the use of a certain graphical framework:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'qt5' is currently running
```

Therefore I would like to ask if there is a way to determine all processes that are currently using `qt5` and depending on the result kill those process, so that I can run my script. (The script worked before the qt5 issue just fine - no idea by which application this new issue was caused).

Comment: You can use `lsof` to find processes that use a certain file. If you know which files are involved in "using qt5" than you can check these.

Comment: @Lucas is there a way to do it when I only have the information from the error message to determine why/for which applications qt5 is running and how to stop qt5? (There seems to be no process called qt5 or similar - at least htop doesn't provide any results to me)

Comment: You ask your package manager about all installed packages that have anything to do with qt5. Then ask the  package manager about all installed packages that use these (recursively). Then list all files of all these packages. (Maybe only executable files?) Check against that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finds the first 5 pids on my machine using **libnss_files-2.23.so**.

```
$ for p in /proc/[0-9]*
    do test -d $p/map_files && 
    sudo ls -l $p/map_files | 
        awk -vpid=$(basename  $p) -vname=libnss_files-2.23.so -F '->' \
            '$2 ~ name {print pid; exit}'
  done |
  head -5 
1114
1155
12066
12148
12156
```

These days on Linux, *find all pids with property X* is frequently solved with procfs.

Comment: Does libnss_files have anything to do with qt5? Or is there some file that will probably be used by a process using qt5?

Comment: The library I chose was arbitrary; I don't use Qt.  ISTM likely that all programs running under Qt will be linked to some runtime support library.  If the OP finds one likely candidate, the above script can serve as a basis for searching the process tree in the way he wants.